# How to develop tests for methods called in the initializer of a complex Python class?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, class

I am hoping to get some advice on better understanding developing tests for more complex class with many methods.

I am currently working on a set of algorithms and reports that will all use data of a similar structure. I have created a class so I can simply initialize it when I need it and be sure I have all my DataFrames and other data in the correct format whenever I want.

I do this additionally due to the fact that the aggregation of this data is quite time consuming. While I use spreadsheet imports in this example, for another data attribute it could involve a SQL pull.

Using this class I will build out different reports or other calculations that work by using the attributes in this class. So for example:

```
# Expensive DAM process...
data = CoreData(run_date='11262019')

# Now just use the current state of data attributes to do what I need...
some_function1(data.df_client, data.df_product)
some_function2(data.run_date)
```

Here is a skeleton of the idea of the class. I call a few "private" methods in the initializer that do the work of assembling the data attributes. This involves a method that even calls additional calculation methods to further proceed with the initialization.

Then it would have additional "public" methods like `CoreData.summarize_import_info` that I could call that might report or do other data cuts or calculations with the initialized data.

```
import pandas as pd

class CoreData(object):

    # Path to read in Excel data.
    path = 'C:'

    def __init__(self, run_date):
        """Initializer sets up case for a particular date."""

        self.run_date = run_date

        # Call more complex methods to initialize data.
        self._import_data()
        self._rename_dataframe_columns()
        self._merge_items()
        self._call_analysis_methods()

    def _import_data(self):
        """Read in spreadsheets into DataFrames."""
        file_input = CoreData.path + self.run_date + '_data.xlsx'

        self.df_region = pd.read_excel(file_input, sheet_name='Region')
        self.df_client = pd.read_excel(file_input, sheet_name='Client')

    def _rename_columns(self):
        """Adjust DataFrames to only include desired columns."""
        self.df_region = self.df_region[CoreData.cols_region]
        self.df_client = self.df_client[CoreData.cols_client]

    def _merge_items(self):
        """Merge core data to create new product level frame."""
        # Bring in attributes as copies.
        df_region = self.df_region.copy()
        df_client = self.df_client.copy()

        # Perform some slice to get US rows.
        mask_us = (df_region['COUNTRY'] == 'US')
        df_cut = df_region.loc[mask_us]

        # Merge two initial frames.
        df_all = df_cut.merge(df_client, how='left', on='PRODUCT')

        self.df_product = df_all

    def _call_analysis_methods(self):
        self._transform_data()
        self._multiply_data()
        self._allocate_risk()

    def _transform_data(self):
        """Do some complicated transformng..."""
        # Assume there is lots of code in each of these...
        pass

    def _multiply_data(self):
        """Calculate revenue by another complicated calcualtion."""
        # Assume there is lots of code in each of these...
        pass

    def _allocate_risk(self):
        """Calculate client level exposure."""
        # Assume there is lots of code in each of these...
        pass

    def summarize_import_info(self):
        return 'We imported with {0}.'.format(self.run_date))


    cols_region = ['COUNTRY', 'PRODUCT', 'CUSTOMERS', 'ANOTHERONE']
    cols_client = ['NAME', 'PRODUCT', 'FEE']
```

My questions are:

1. Is it appropriate style-wise to call this many methods in the `CoreData.__init__` method to set up the data attributes? Or should this be broken up?
2. As these objects evolve with time, the spreadsheets might add new fields, the team delivering them will likely mess up or change their format, they might have missing data. How do I test this class with `unittest`? Initially it felt like breaking up the initialization steps into methods with a single purpose each made more sense, but now I am realizing there is no way to do a test on one of these "private" methods that got called during the initialization:

```
import unittest

class TestCoreData(unittest.TestCase):

    # This test would work fine because I initialize the class, call the
    # method then test the result.
    def test_summarize_import_info(self):
        """Test our summary method produces the correct output."""
        data = CoreData(run_date='11262019')
        msg = data.summarize_import_info()

        self.assertEqual(msg, 'We imported with 11262019.')

    # This won't work as it is locked up inside __init__!
    def test__rename_columns(self):
        """Tests the columns of the imported frame match the expected list."""

        data = CoreData(run_date='11262019')
        data._rename_columns()                            # Already called...                         
        self.assertEqual(data.df_client.columns.tolist(), # These lines won't
                         data.cols_client)                # work right.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How do you suggest I proceed in this scenario? I am very concerned about getting these initial structures down correctly, because as they scale, without tests and good initial design they will become nightmares due to all their dependencies down the line.

Any recommendations on style or best practices here would be hugely appreciated. I am a self taught programmer so forgive me if some of this would be obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like this might be better suited for code review

Comment: One suggestion is to decide what *invariants* ought to hold for any instance, and then make assertions in a unit test (or even in the class itself). For instance, one invariant might be:  for each client, the region ID refers to a record in the regions dataframe (referential integrity). Another invariant might be that all risk allocations add up to 100% (or some other value).  In your tests, you could explicitly check these.

Comment: you also need to mock loading the CSVs, you are assuming whoever runs this has these CVSs in a specific location/naming convention